# PHP $_POSt array empty, even when manually typing the url

Tags: php, arrays, post

I'm, running the file post.php on my server:

```
<?php
    print sizeof($_POST);
?>
```

and the url is `my.server/test/post.php?test=1`

and it's printing 0

Help

Comment: my.server/test/post.php?test=1'   us e GET metodh not POST so try using  $_GET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters placed on the querystring in a url are passed to PHP in the `$_GET` array.

Also you may find `print_r()` a better way of seeing what's in an array

```
<?php
    print sizeof($_GET);
    print_r($_GET);
?>
```

Or if you want the PHP code to work for GET and POST use

```
<?php
    print sizeof($_REQUEST);
    print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

Comment: Beat me to it!!

Comment: :) Hi there @JayBlanchard

Comment: Howdy @RiggsFolly :)

Comment: No need, we all start out in the same place

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$_GET` for URL parameters. `$_POST` is for HTTP post requests. Look at [$_POST documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

So just replace `$_POST` with `$_GET` and it will work as you expect.

```
<?php
    print sizeof($_GET);
?>
```